# Unable to change url of sub site

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

I want to change the URL of an sub site as it is misspelled.

When we try to change the URL in the designer and in the site, but both are getting the following error:

> It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid
>   file or folder that is not in the current Web.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using PowerShell?  The Set-SPWeb command should do the trick if you are on premises.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607732.aspx